# Remove some value (that contain a specific character) in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several csv files and I want to remove some data in a specific column (I could do this manually but I have a lot of files...).

Here an example of what my file looks like:

```
col1 <- c('a','b','c')
col2 <-c('xxx','xxx-PAS','xxx-PAS')
col3 <- c(44,456,896)
z <- data.frame(col1,col2)
z
```

In my column of interest (col2 in the example), I want to remove all the lines that contains '-PAS' so I'll have a smaller files without those values, but I don't know how...

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `grep` to find the substring in the column and `invert` the match

```
z[grep('PAS', z$col2, invert = TRUE),]
#  col1 col2
#1    a  xxx
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun!